# Copy last 20 columns with non-blank cells in range

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing macro for excel in VBA. Macro is collecting table data with web query. Data is form tables for soccer from xscores.com (for example one league) http://www.xscores.com/soccer/tables/england/premier_league/2014-2015/l/4/5
Everything is working like charm, except one thing. First this is the part of code that I have problem
http://pastebin.com/HKTT6Paw

This is part with W D L stuff. Web query is collecting whole table. It is supposed to collect 10 home, 10 away and 20 total (thats 40 cells). But in some leagues (because of delayed games) is collecting 11 home or 12 away or similar, with blank cells. I need just first 5 columns in range of total. My idea for resolving this problem is to get some range, check wich is last populated column in range and from last populated column to collect that and 19 prior to this columns (cells in range). To get just totals (total is always 20 games). And paste it in other part of sheet.
Is there solution in macro to check last populated column and take last 20 populated columns with range of cells? (in this example that will be range BR4:CL23)
Or if someone has better solution, can give some free suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: PUŠI KURAC MAJMUNE, IDEŠ I EDITUJEŠ MI SVAKI JEBENI PUT PITANJE I DAJEŠ MINUS MAJMUNE JEDAN RETARDIRANI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This macro will copy the last 20 columns of the Activesheet to Sheet2 cell **A1:**

```
Sub Kolumn()
    Dim r As Range, nLastColumn As Long
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    nLastColumn = r.Columns.Count + r.Column - 1
    Range(Cells(1, nLastColumn - 19), Cells(1, nLastColumn)).EntireColumn.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, this is not bad its half of what I need. But, my range is not same always. I need to check last populated column in range and from that last populated column to do this what you did. Copy last 20 columns in range.

Comment: @MorsViolenta  My code does that.  **nLastColumn** will always be the last populated column in the worksheet.  So if columns *A* thru *Z* contain any data, then **nLastColumn** will be *26*

Comment: Ok. Thats good. But, only this to ask. I not need to copy exactly whole columns just range (of last column) + 19 columns behind last columns in range. In my example. Start range it will be AV4:CS23. And end range what is going to need and copy it is going to be BR4:CL23. In this case in some other case maybe it will be BS4:CM23 or BP4:CJ23. I hope that you understand. And thanks again for your help.

Comment: I am apologize. Your code is fine thats what i needed. I just thinked a little bit that can be done all in one sheet. But doesnt matter. Thanks again a lot for this!